# Comparing 2 lists out of order

Tags: python, list, function, python-3.x, for-loop

I want to compare 2 lists, say `A` and `B`.

```
A = [1,2,3]
B = [3,1,2]
```

I want to write a function to check if all the items in A are present in B or not.
i.e. the function should return `True` for the example above.
Note: The items of my lists are non-hashable objects.

For this, I wrote this code:

```
for elem in A:
    if elem not in B:
        return False
return True
```

The code works fine.
But I want a more efficient and a more pythonic way to do this.

Comment: `sorted(A) == sorted(B)`? Or something with sets, depending on what your comparisons should be (it's not clear from that one trivial example).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I can't sort the lists. This was just an example. I am working with different objects in my list.

Comment: Actually no problem, if you don't do `A = sorted(A)` then `A` wouldn't be sorted.

Comment: `sorted` creates new lists. And if the example isn't representative, show one that is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `all`

```
all(i in B for i in A)
```

Example:

```
>>> A = [1,2,3]
>>> B = [3,1,2]
>>> all(i in B for i in A)
True
>>> B = [3,1,4]
>>> all(i in B for i in A)
False
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works fine. However, can't I improve upon the time complexity ?

Comment: @KshitijSaraogi: if you want a better asymptotic complexity, then you must use other data structures, like other answers here suggest

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini I just wanted to know if this was the best I can do in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Counter`, which runs in O(n) time.

```
from collections import Counter

A = [1,2,3]
B = [3,1,2]

print(Counter(A) == Counter(B)) # Prints True
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. The objects are non-hashable, so I dont think this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think using **set** is a good solution for this task :

```
In [2]: A = [1,2,3]

In [3]: B = [3,1,2]
In [5]: set(A)==set(B)
Out[5]: True
```

This code will have O(n) complexity for more information you can check [this link](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)

If you don't want to use set you can try to sort lists :

```
def cmp(A,B):
  A1 = sorted(A)
  B1 = sorted(B)
  for item in A1:
    if binary_search(B1,item)==-1:
        return False
  for item in B1:
    if binary_search(A1,item)==-1:
        return False
  return True
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. However, I would not prefer to make a set object.
I want to do the operation on lists.

Comment: @KshitijSaraogi than you can sort two lists, It will have O(N*logN) complexity. Check edited answer

Comment: The items are unhashable objects. Moreover, I don't intend to sort the list even if this was not the case.

Comment: @KshitijSaraogi why do you even need hash to sort objects? what's wrong with sorting? This doesn't affect original lists.

Comment: I know. I just don't want to do it.